# modalViewController: properties and variables

Tags: uiviewcontroller, modalviewcontroller

I really need some help with my iPad app. The following scenario:

- mainView loads
- mainView sets some variables
- mainView presents modalView
- modalView adds objects to a mainView's mutableArray
- modalView dismisses and calls a mainView's method

Now my question:
How do I access variables and methods without creating new instances for each?!

When I do `mainView *main = [[mainView alloc] init];` in the modalView, to access methods and variables, the old instance gets destroyed and I loose all my variables when returning back to the mainView.

Thanks for every little help! With kind regards, Julian

Comment: I do not understand, *why* do you alloc a new mainView. Simply don't do it.

Comment: _Not_ allocating the mainView will cause the app to crash with **SIGABRT** How should I implement the parent (mainView) then?!

Comment: Don't *re*alloc it. You need one controller instance, alloc only one.

Comment: Okay, I'll try. But how should I transfer the data then?!

Comment: I guess, you should read the basics about IOS view controllers (https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457) and the delegate design pattern (https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/General/Conceptual/CocoaEncyclopedia/DelegatesandDataSources/DelegatesandDataSources.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010810-CH11-SW1)

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is to add a property to your `modalView`, something like `parent`. Then, just before you call `presentModalViewController` from your `mainView`, you'd set the `modalView.parent = self;` This way you have a back-reference to the `mainView` (the specific instance) from your `modalView`.

Another way is to make your `mainView` a singleton object. This may or may not be optimal for you, depending on your application's design. The way I've done singleton objects is as follows:
+ Create a global/static variable in your `mainView` (e.g. mv_). The type should be the same as the class (i.e. `mainView`). Initialize it to `nil`.
+ Create a class method to alloc & init that variable (if an instance doesn't already exist) or to return it as it is (if you've already initialized it). This can be as simple as:

```
+ (mainView *) getMainView()
{
    if (!mv_)
        _mv = [[self alloc] init];
    return mv_;
}
```

+ Then, whenever you need to access the mainView singleton object, you just call `getMainView`. There are some quirks when using this methodology though, so make sure your application behaves as you want it to if you decide to go that way.